# How to declare the type of a variadic templated class in a simple way

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a variadic templated struct in VS2013 that uses a templated function to allow automatic type deduction.

```
template<typename... T> struct BitVector {
   BitVector(T... args){...}
}
using BitVector_t = struct BitVector<T...>;

template<typename... T>
std::shared_ptr<BitVector_t<T...>>
CreateBitVector(T... args) {
   auto v = new BitVector_t<T...>(args...);
   return std::shared_ptr<BitVector_t<T...>(v);
}
```

With this, I can define the items and defaultvalues of my bitvector in one single line. Furthermore I can easily create a BitVector by calling

```
auto mybitvector = CreateBitVector("Item1", int(1), "Item2", std::string("defval")...);
```

where the types are deduced from the function parameters.
This works great with ***auto***, 
but if I need a certain BitVector as a class member, where no *auto* is allowed, all efforts to have a clean and simple API, where types and default values are just specified at a ***single*** location, seem to be gone, as a class member would require an additional declaration like

```
std::shared_ptr<
BitVector<char const*, int, 
char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> 
mMyBitVector;
```

Can anyone imagine a simple workaround, to get the member declaration, without writing the parameter types explicitly a second time?

Comment: _"... without writing the parameter types explicitly a second time?"_ May be a typedef?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [`using` type alias ftw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

Comment: @luk32 Should work equally well.

Comment: You could also do an 'evil' macro: `#define member_creator(a,b) decltype(b) a = b` (or the like). Usage: `member_creator(mybitvector, CreateBitVector("Item1", int(1), "Item2", std::string("defval")...));` would create a member named `mybitvector`of the same type as returned by `CreateBitVector`. Maybe not the prettiest solution.

Comment: @Banan it is pretty in a sense that the definition / declaration is self-contained (i.e. all at one location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comment, `decltype` may help:

```
#define AUTO_MEMBER(memberName, init) decltype(init) memberName = (init)

class C
{
public:    
    //...
private:
    AUTO_MEMBER(mMyBitVector, CreateBitVector("Item1", 1, "Item2", std::string("defval")));
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/HYdqEs)

but I would prefer be explicit on member type (and may be using some `typedef`).

Answer (score 1):

Create a type alias with all the template parameters.

```
using MyBitVector_t = std::shared_ptr<BitVector<char const*, int, std::string>>;
```

Use the type alias to declare a member.

```
MyBitVector_t mMyBitVector;
```

The type alias can be used to define the return types of functions and types of arguments of functions too.